# How to Add and update the comments for the PDF file using c#

Tags: c#

Now I am working in the process of Insert and Update the comment for the pdf file using c# code. I want to Know the any possible way to insert a comment inside the pdf file. Anyone Know about this, Please reply and some reference for this process.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft does have very limited support for PDF in operating system APIs and it has come only recently in Windows 8 for modern applications (now called UWP) and that support doesn't go as far as updating comments.

So you need to use the 3rd party library. As far as I can tell SharpPDF is the only free library worth something, but I failed to open many PDFs in it so I can't recommend it. So I think you would need to search for some commercial library, I am aware of several of them that can do the job (e.g XfiniumPDF, iTextSharp etc) and you'll get the documentation when you license them.